# Extract Wikipedia Entities from Text

Tags: python, nlp, nltk, wikipedia, entity-linking

Is there any way we can extract all the wikipedia entities from the text using Wikipedia2Vec? Or is there any other way to do the same.

Example:

```
Text : "Scarlett Johansson is an American actress."  
Entities : [ 'Scarlett Johansson' , 'American' ]
```

I want to do it in Python

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use [spacy](https://spacy.io/):

```py
import spacy
import en_core_web_sm
nlp = en_core_web_sm.load()
doc = doc = nlp('Scarlett Johansson is an American actress.')
print([(X.text, X.label_) for X in doc.ents])
```

And you get:

```
[('Scarlett Johansson', 'PERSON'), ('American', 'NORP')]
```

Find more in [spacy documentation](https://spacy.io/usage/linguistic-features#named-entities).

Answer (score 1):

Here's an NLTK version (may not be as good as SpaCy):

```
from nltk import Tree
from nltk import ne_chunk, pos_tag, word_tokenize

def get_continuous_chunks(text, chunk_func=ne_chunk):
    chunked = chunk_func(pos_tag(word_tokenize(text)))
    continuous_chunk = []
    current_chunk = []

    for subtree in chunked:
        if type(subtree) == Tree:
            current_chunk.append(" ".join([token for token, pos in subtree.leaves()]))
        elif current_chunk:
            named_entity = " ".join(current_chunk)
            if named_entity not in continuous_chunk:
                continuous_chunk.append(named_entity)
                current_chunk = []
        else:
            continue

    return continuous_chunk


text = 'Scarlett Johansson is an American actress.'
get_continuous_chunks(text)
```